# Destroy vagrant machine if chef-solo fails

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, execution, chef-solo

I have 5 machines described in Vagrantfile and have some chef-solo simple recipes. I want to identify machine where chef execution failed.

What I've tried so far: tried to run **vagrant up** with **--destroy-on-error** flag so then if on some machine chef-solo fails then I could see them in **vagrant status** in **not created state**, but it did not happen. After **vagrant up** all machines have **running** state.

Maybe there is a way to configure chef to store execution info somewhere on running machine and then I can have that info with **vagrant ssh**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The machines are in running state because vagrant needs the machine to run before it can execute chef provisioning.

what you could do is to set chef running in debug log

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    # ...
    chef.log_level = :debug
  end
end
```

I know in the past there were no output to file, it might have changed but I am not sure and output still goes to STDOUT.

Comment: Yep if there's no log file that will be the option